How to collect ANR logs on devices below Android 11?
My device is running Android 9. On the Crashlytics page of the Firebase console, I can't view the ANR (Application Not Responding) logs. It is indicated that only the ANR logs of devices with Android 11 and above are collected. How can I solve this problem?
I am currently using the free version. Do I need to upgrade to the paid version?
I hope that I can directly collect ANR (Application Not Responding) logs of low - version Android through Firebase, or there are other methods to collect ANR logs and report them to the Firebase platform.

there is no such possibility in Firebase strictly, also not in paid version, thats the limitation of Android
but I think there might be some work around... there is a lib called ANR-WatchDog and in short you can get onAppNotResponding callback when ANR occurs. Implement it on lower Android versions and inside you can push some message to Firebase with
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
where e is your custom exception, which may contain collected useful info (e.g. RuntimeException("BOOM, ANR! wasLogged:$logged threads num:$threadCount")). Not the same as on Android 11+, but best I've figured out in similar case...
note that Firebase is sometimes reporting data not during current runtime, but in next session, especially when crash occurs - it may be (probably is) reported with next app start
